# Loading middleware based on user interaction

Tags: node.js, middleware

I always have seen people use the `use` function to load their middlewares inside the main app mostly. In this case the middleware sits in the server memory.

I want to know is it possible to load some of the middlewares that I want just when a user clicks on something (for example log in to my page and based on their access Node loads some middlewares in the memory). I also want to know how could I unload a middleware (when they log out their dedicated middleware unloads from the memory).

Comment: Express handles multiple requests with the same middleware, this doesn't make sense. If you need to keep track of who's logged in on the server side, you need *sessions*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to load different middleware flow for different users.

What you can do:

1. add middlewares for specific routes
2. edit your middleware to have a check inside it for the specific condition you need if it should go through or not.
3. example:

```

```
const SomeMiddleware = function(next) {
  if (userClicked) {
    //run middleware stuff
  }
  next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how can i unload a middleware if I want ?

Comment: @Sam AFAIK there's no way to un-`use` middleware.

Comment: as @jonrsharpe there is no way to unuse it, maybe if you really hack the framework you are using. But there is no reason to do that. Use the above options.